# Is there something like coproduct categories

Tags: category-theory, products

While I understand the concept of *product category*, I do wonder if there is something like a *coproduct category*, where we have functors

$$
P: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C} \coprod \mathcal{D} \\
Q: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C} \coprod \mathcal{D} \\
$$

fulfilling a universal property:

$$
\forall R: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{O}, T: \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{O}. \exists! F: \mathcal{C} \coprod \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{O}. PF = R \wedge QF = T.
$$

In fact this should also happen to *category of diagrams* for the coproduct as a limit.
As I understand it, there are certain categories, where the *product category* and the product expressed in limits doesn't match, which expresses the need for the product category.

Is there such a need for a *coproduct category*?

Comment: $\mathbf{Cat}$ is complete and cocomplete, so there are certainly coproduct categories. The product category is a totally different thing than the "product expressed in limits" unless you are talking about in $\mathbf{Cat}$ where there is no difference. A product category (i.e. a product in $\mathbf{Cat}$) is always a category. A product in some arbitrary category is an object (equipped with some arrows) in that category. Again, unless that category is $\mathbf{Cat}$ (or possibly some subcategory), these will never be the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there exists a coproduct category $\mathcal C\sqcup\mathcal D$ of categories $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal D$, namely it is their **disjoint union**, with the natural embeddings, just like in the category of sets, graphs or topological spaces.

The *product category* $\mathcal C\times\mathcal D\ $ **is** one that satisfies the universal property of products in the category $\mathcal Cat$ of small categories.

Comment: Incidentally, we can use the fact that the functor $\mathsf{Ob}:\mathbf{cat}\to\mathbf{Set}$, which takes a small category to its set of objects, has both a left and right adjoint to show that any (co)limit of small categories will have as its set of objects a corresponding (co)limit of sets. In this example, this implies that the coproduct of (small) categories has as its set of objects the disjoint union of the sets of objects of the components. This doesn't say anything about the arrows though.